# Finding minimum and maximum

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, logic

I need to write a repetition program that gets 5 numbers and show the max and the min numbers.
I got this for the moment but does't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,maximum, minimum, number;
    int count=0;
    const int n = 5;
    for(i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("enter number %d :",i+1) ;
        scanf("%d",&number) ;
        maximum=(number>maximum);
        minimum=(number<minimum);
    }
    printf("\n maximum is :%d ,& minimum is :%d ",maximum, minimum) ;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

This just shows `1` ans `0` as max and min. What's the problem behind my logic?

Comment: JAce, you should probably communicate to everyone what answer helped you so that others with the same issue do not make a duplicate post.

Answer (score 7):

Include the following header file:

```
#include <limits.h>
```

... then change the following:

```
int i, maximum, minimum, number;
```

... to:

```
int i, maximum, minimum, number;

maximum = INT_MIN;
minimum = INT_MAX;
```

... and change the following:

```
maximum = ( number > maximum );
minimum = ( number < minimum );
```

... to:

```
maximum = (number > maximum) ? number : maximum;
minimum = (number < minimum) ? number : maximum;
```

... the entire program could be written as follows:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
  int maximum = INT_MIN, 
      minimum = INT_MAX,
      number;

  int const inputs_upperbound = 5;

  for ( int i = 0; i < inputs_upperbound; i++ ) {
    printf( "Enter number %d: ", i );
    scanf( "%d", &number );

    if ( number > maximum ) maximum = number;
    if ( number < minimum ) minimum = number;
  }

  printf( "The minimum number was %d, and the maximum number was %d.\n", minimum, maximum );

  return 0;
}
```

**Remark:**

The logical operator `>` and `<` returns `true` or `false` (hence any non-zero integer, 1 for `true` or 0 for `false`). What you are intending to do is mutate the `maximum` and `minimum` values with respect to that result, and hence the `?` and `:` operators are required. Alternatively, you can use the control flow statement `if` as follows:

```
if ( number > maximum ) maximum = number;
if ( minimum < minimum ) minimum = number;
```

You should also have your `main` function specifying that no arguments should be passed to it by using the special `void` parameter, as follows:

```
int main( void ) {
  // ... code.
}
```

... [from C11 specification 6:11:6](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (page: 179)

> The **use of function declarators with empty parentheses** (not
>   prototype-format parameter type declarators) **is an obsolescent
>   feature**.

Comment: thanks it works for the maximum but not for the minimum still =0

Comment: @zubergu, and where did I make my mistake? Point it out so I can make the appropriate correction.

Comment: I'd go with the if statements in this case and not the ?: operator. In my opinion, the ?: only adds extra confusion in this case.

Comment: @zubergu It is quite common practice to initialize max to INT_MIN and min to INT_MAX for algorithms like this.

Comment: @Lundin, I felt it was appropriate to mention both to give a complete answer to the two standard solutions to this problem. He is also performing ternary operations so I would even argue that the conditional operator is more appropriate under this circumstance (especially since it is only one expression).

Comment: @zubergu, then propose your alternate solution and show the entire snippet of code so we can see how you would implement this problem. To re-iterate what Lundin remarked, it is extremely common to initialize a variable that holds a maximum value to the smallest possible value with respect to its data type, vice-versa for minimum variable.

Comment: @zubergu The variable which should contain the maximum number is initialized with the smallest possible number it can contain (and vice versa). Then no matter what the input from the user is, it is guaranteed to be larger or equal to the value already present in that variable.

Comment: @JAce, I included the implementation of your program following my suggestions -- this should solve all of your issues and introduce you to solving maximum/minimum problems.

Comment: @zubergu You should hold it against yourself, and learn several lessons from it. No one else cares.

Answer (score 1):

(number>maximum) equals 1 (boolean true) when, well, it's true, and 0 when it's not. Same with minumum. You don't make assignment of number to maximum or minimum at any place, only assignment to maximum, then minimum of boolean 0 and 1 when making comparison (<,>). If you want to get max number you have to assign maximum=number, if number>maximum. Hope it helps.

Oh, other thing is you didn't initialize (give starting values) for maximum and minimum variables. So when You compare number>maximum what's your value of maximum at this point? Think about it.

Comment: @zubergu indeed he gave me the aswer but now i get what the library <limits.h> means  and help me alot

Answer (score 0):

You don't require limits.h.

Use the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,maximum, minimum, number;
    int count=0;
    const int n = 5;
    for(i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("enter number %d :",i+1) ;
        scanf("%d",&number) ;
        maximum=(number>maximum)? number : maximum;
        minimum=(number<minimum)? number : minimum;
    }
    printf("\n maximum is :%d ,& minimum is :%d ",maximum, minimum) ;
    getch();   
    return 0;
}
```

This works.